# Supporting permissions in Laravel Passport and its substitutions

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-passport, api-authorization

Does `Laravel Passport` support having permissions on routes, methods, and a number of requests? e.g., the user can only send `GET` request, or the user can only send 50 requests for the special route, or the user only has access to special routes.

If not, do you know any package in `laravel` or other `PHP frameworks` that provide such facilities for API authentication and authorization?

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to make use of the middleware `throttle`.

for example:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api', 'throttle:60,1')->group(function () {
...
}
```